# Add extension to base classes in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am adding a method on Number in javascript. Now i want to make this method available in typescript, but i have no idea how to added it via the definition files.

My method is

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
    var n = this,
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};
```

I was thinking of adding this definition file, but it gives me the error **'Duplicate identifier Number'**

```
declare module Number{
    export var formatMoney:Function;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to defining the method on `Number`'s prototype, it needs to be defined on the `Number` interface:

```
interface Number {
    formatMoney(c, d, t): string;   
}
```

You can define this anywhere in the application and TypeScript will merge it with the existing `Number` interface via [Declaration Merging](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Declaration-Merging).

By the way, I would *highly* recommend you give the variables in the function better names than `c`, `d`, `t`, `s`, `j`, etc... Since the variables don't have a descriptive name, it will take a developer longer to understand what those variables mean and it makes the code less maintainable.

Additionally, I would recommend giving the parameters type information and to use [default parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-optional-and-default-parameters):

```
interface Number {
    formatMoney(value: number, decimalMark?: string, thousandsSeparator?: string): string;  
}

Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(value: number, decimalMark = ".", thousandsSeparator = ",") {
    // etc...
};
```

Also, take note that `i` is not declared in the function.